# Upload to app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

So when I was trying to upload my app to the app store and I run into this error and could not find any help. Nothing I could do helped. Below are two screenshots of my screen:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you create a certificate in Apple Developer?

Comment: What's the exact wording of the error?

Comment: Do you have a paid membership of the developer program?

Comment: Recommend you paste as much detail about the error as possible.

Comment: Remove the AppleID and then login again its may helps you.

Comment: What s the error here?!!

Comment: Use Application Loader to upload

Comment: There is no error but my account does not show up there even though I have  a paid developer program.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Application Loader that can help you upload your app to AppStore without any uncertain errors.